# Второй вложенный список содержит элементы из первого в выводе компилятора

Tags: python

Мне нужно сделать так чтобы мой тестовый компилятор работал с такой текстовой конструкцией:

```
def A{
ldarg a
push 2
store b
fetch a
fetch b
add
ret
}

def main{
push 3
call A
ret }
```

Нужно чтобы в структуре func_co было:
`func_co=[[ldarg ,a,push, 2,store, b,fetch ,a,fetch, b,add,ret]] #здесь можно вкладывать списки с другими функциями`,
а в `main_co=[push ,3,call ,A,ret]`
Делаю такой код:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
code="""{defA {\n  
#arg a \
ldarg a \
push 2 \
store b \
fetch a \
fetch b \
add \
ret } \
m { \
push 3\
call 0\
ret\
 }}"""
func_env={}
global_env={}
func_co=[]
main_co=[]
func_names={}
tmp_part_fu_co=[]

k_w=['ldarg','push','store','fetch','ret','call']


class Compiler:
    def obrabotka(self):       
        steck=[]
        tok=''
        num_cur_char=0
        nomer_fu_co_in_lst=0
        state=0

        for i in code:
            tok+=i
            if i=='{':
                steck.append(i)
                state=1 #скобки открываются
            elif i=='}':
                state=2 #скобки закрываются
                if len(steck)==0:
                    print('Oshibka skobok')
                if steck[-1]=='{':
                    steck=steck[:-1]
                else:
                    print('Oshibka skobok')
            elif i=='\n':
                tok=''
            elif i==' ': 
                print(tok)
                tok=''
            if state==1:
                if tok in k_w or tok.isdigit():
                   tmp_part_fu_co.append(tok)
                   tok=''  
                print(tok)

            if state==2:
              print('***')
              func_co.append(tmp_part_fu_co)
              state=0       

        if len(steck)!=0:
            print('Oshibka skobok')


c=Compiler()
c.obrabotka()
print(func_co)
```

Дает такой вывод:

```
[['ldarg', 'push', '2', 'store', 'fetch', 'fetch', 'ret', 'push', '3', 'call', '0', 'ret'], ['ldarg', 'push', '2', 'store', 'fetch', 'fetch', 'ret', 'push', '3', 'call', '0', 'ret']]
```

Как исправить код?
Получается `[['ldarg', 'push', '2', 'store', 'fetch', 'fetch', 'ret', 'push', '3', 'call', '0', 'ret'], ['ldarg', 'push', '2', 'store', 'fetch', 'fetch', 'ret', 'push', '3', 'call', '0', 'ret']]`, а нужно чтобы `[['ldarg', 'push', '2', 'store', 'fetch', 'fetch', 'ret'], ['push', '3', 'call', '0', 'ret']]`

Comment: явно упомяните в чём отличие полученного вывода от желаемого.

Comment: Получается 
[['ldarg', 'push', '2', 'store', 'fetch', 'fetch', 'ret', 'push', '3', 'call', '0', 'ret'], ['ldarg', 'push', '2', 'store', 'fetch', 'fetch', 'ret', 'push', '3', 'call', '0', 'ret']],
а нужно чтобы
[['ldarg', 'push', '2', 'store', 'fetch', 'fetch', 'ret'], ['push', '3', 'call', '0', 'ret']]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы добавляете один и тот же список `tmp_part_fu_co` в качестве элементов `func_co` списка, поэтому `func_co[0] is func_co[1]` у вас. Пример:

```
>>> outer = []
>>> inner = [1]
>>> outer.append(inner)
>>> outer
[[1]]
>>> inner.append(2)
>>> outer
[[1, 2]]
>>> outer.append(inner)
>>> outer
[[1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

`list.append` метод не копирует аргумент, а добавляет элемент (ссылку на него) как есть.

Создавайте новый список руками, если вам нужны отдельные списки здесь. В коде и другие проблемы есть.

Comment: Спасибо!Так понятно.